# android navigation drawer material design webview no scrolling vertically

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, navigation-drawer

I am new to android , in my application am using navigation drawer activity (Materail Design) and have a webview in a Fragment . The Navigation loads webview without any problem . But i cannot scroll the webview vertically , i can do horizontally .I can see the vertial scroll bar on horzontal scroll , but not functional.

Here is the Fragment XML code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDefaultGray"
    tools:context="com.cell.cell.fragments.MainWebViewFragmant">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webViewMainWebview"
         />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cell.cell.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried different solution , such as NestedWebView and tried to put the webview tag inside NestedScrollview ,but no luck.
Please provide a solution for this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally wrapping your FrameLayout in your AppBarLayout, move your FrameLayout underneath the AppBarLayout.

So what is happening is the AppBarLayout is taking your scroll event instead of the WebView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cell.cell.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <!-- Move your FrameLayout outside the AppBarLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Then in kitkat devices , The status bar hides That's y added inside AppBarLayout tag

Comment: in kitkat there is no coloring the status bar the way it works on Lollipop devices, this is the default behavior.

Comment: Tried , but the app status bar fills the screen ...  Cannot view the Fragment

Comment: Ahh, yeah you need to change height of AppBarLayout to wrap_content, see edit above

Comment: Thanks ! saved my day and whole week end